# Why does mvccontrib's AssertViewRendered().ForView("Edit") fail due to view name being full cshtml path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have the following unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_Returns_Edit_View()
    {
        // Act
        ActionResult result = _controller.Add();

        // Verify
        result.AssertViewRendered().ForView("Edit");
    }
```

This should be passing, since the Add action is returning the Edit view.  However, this assertion fails with the following exception

```
MvcContrib.TestHelper.ActionResultAssertionException: Expected view name 'Edit', actual was '~/Views/JobSearch/Edit.cshtml'
```

Why is the view name coming back as the full path name?  Could this be due to my usage of T4MVC, and if so how can I get this to pass?

---

*Edit* The Add view looks like this:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View(MVC.JobSearch.Views.Edit, new JobSearch());
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Can you post the Controller.Add() function? I've had a play and the only way I could get any odd results in examples similar to yours involved doing odd things in the action...

Comment: I added what the `Controller.Add()` method looks like

Comment: What does MVC.JobSearch.Views.Edit return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test against the T4MVC value like this :

```
result.AssertViewRendered().ForView(MVC.JobSearch.Views.Edit);
```

I think it's the cleaner solution... If you have better let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess I just didn't investigate into the T4MVC code to get a better look at what is happening.  It seems that the `MVC.JobSearch.Views.Edit` is equal to `"~/Views/JobSearch/Edit.cshtml"`, and so `.ForView()` is testing against the same exact view name that is described in the `View()` method call.

Thanks for the help.